# .Net wrapper eventhandling

Tags: events, event-handling, wrapper

Situation:
I have a dll and a program which should use this dll with Late binding.

Every method is working are also events. For excample there is a logging event. I want to an own logging method in the program but here is my problem. I don't no how.

dll log class (c#):

```
/// <summary>
/// log helper class.
/// </summary>
public static class Log {

    // ######### Enum #############################################################################################

    /// <summary>
    /// Log level enum.
    /// </summary>
    public enum LogLevel {
        None = -1,
        Debug = 0,
        Info = 1,
        Warn = 2,
        Error = 3,
        Fatal = 4
    }


    // ######### Events ###########################################################################################

    /// <summary>
    /// log helper class log event.
    /// </summary>
    public static event EventHandler<HelperLogEventArgs> HelperLog;


    // ######### Constructor ######################################################################################

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    static Log() {
        HelperLog += DebugLog;
    }


    // ######### Methods ##########################################################################################

    /// <summary>
    /// log helper class log event handling.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Log event arguments</param>
    public static void OnHelperLog(HelperLogEventArgs e) {
        EventHandler<HelperLogEventArgs> handler = HelperLog;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(null, e);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Log a message to the debug console.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Event sender</param>
    /// <param name="e">Log event arguments</param>
    private static void DebugLog(object sender, HelperLogEventArgs e) {
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format(" [{0}]: {1}", e.logLevel.ToString(), e.message));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Log a message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="level">Log level</param>
    /// <param name="message">Log message</param>
    public static void Log(LogLevel level, string message) {
        HelperLogEventArgs args = new HelperLogEventArgs();
        args.logLevel = level;
        args.logTime = DateTime.Now;
        args.message = message;
        OnHelperLog(args);
    }


    // ######### Help Classes #####################################################################################

    /// <summary>
    /// log helper class event argument class.
    /// </summary>
    public class HelperLogEventArgs : EventArgs {
        /// <summary>
        /// Log message log level.
        /// </summary>
        public Log.LogLevel logLevel;

        /// <summary>
        /// Log message text.
        /// </summary>
        public string message;

        /// <summary>
        /// Log message log timestamp.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime logTime;
    }

}
```

And now I have a Wrapper class in the external program with loads the dll unfortunately in another language (vb.Net.):

```
If _oAssembly Is Nothing Then
    _oAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(sTfsHelperDllPath)
End If

' This will not throw an exception but return nothing.
_oTFSHelper = _oAssembly.CreateInstance("TFSHelper.TFSHelper")
If _oTFSHelper Is Nothing Then
    ' Throw manually an exception on error.
    Throw New Exception("## TFSHelper could not be loaded. ##")
End If
```

Now can somebody show me how I write and add a logging method/ event hander in the external programm with will called then the event  in the ddl is raised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use Reflection to add an event:

```
' Add event Handler
Dim method As MethodInfo = Me.GetType().GetMethod("<NewEventHandlerName>", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public)
Dim eventInfo As EventInfo = _oTFSHelper.GetType().GetEvent("<EventName>")
Dim type As Type = eventInfo.EventHandlerType
Dim handler As [Delegate] = [Delegate].CreateDelegate(type, Me, method)
eventInfo.AddEventHandler(_oTFSHelper, handler)
```